# Uniqueness of Inverse Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have a question regarding the inverse Laplace transform (LT).

I have searched for the formal definition and properties of inverse LT and I know that if
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(s) \quad \forall s>a,
$$
where $f, g$(defined on $[0,\infty)$) are exponential type $a$, then $f(t) = g(t)~\forall t\ge 0$.

My question is: for a general Laplace transform, if $F(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)$ exist for $s\in (a, \infty)$, and $\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(s) = F(s)$ for $s \in (b, \infty), b>a$. Can we draw the conclusion that $g(t)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$?

Comment: What is the distribution of X??

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is not explicit and is expressed in terms of characteristic exponent. I cannot express the distribution without introducing the background and that's why I did not include the distribution in my original post.